# What is the best practice to get the items that have the same items from another array

Tags: javascript, loops

Ok, I know the title is quite complicated but the question is hard to make in one line too.. sorry.

Objective: I want to run a callback when all modules are available
Problem: what is the fastest way?
Example:

the problem begins in the function "runCallbacks" that gets all the new added objects like this:

```
runCallbacks(newItems/*as array ['a','b','c'];*/){
    // now I would need to understand the dependencies of the callbacks
    // each callback might depend on one or more objects
    // iNeed(['a','b'], toRunThis);
    //           |          |-callback to run when those are ready
    //           |-are the dependencies
```

what I was thinking of is this:

```
 callbacks = [[[callbackFunction],['loadedItems'],['notLoadedItems']]]
              |-----------it's a single callback--------------------|
```

has good performance or do you have any better idea?
thanks

Another example

```
this.use(['a', 'b'], function(){/* do something with 'a' and 'b' only when are ready */})
use: function(paths, callback, target/*not used in this case*/){
    // "a", "b", 'c' module is available
    // "d", 'e' module is not available
    this.callbacks.push([[target], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e']]);
    //                               |      |-not loaded
    //                               |-loaded
}

// then an object might be added
this.add({...})

// then will check if this new object may make some callbacks to run
function(newPaths/* ['d'] */){
    // loop all callbacks items
    // remove items from [not loaded array] and put to [loaded array] if
    // exists in newPaths
    // in this case the callback already has: a,b,c; but misses: d,e;
    // now it will add "d" to the loaded array
    // and now only miss the "e" path
```

so if a callback needs "a" and "b" but not exists saves the callback for when both are ready
I add the "a" and "b" module and then I want to know witch callbacks are ready to run;

a callback might have multiple dependences
the "a" module might be used by multiple callbacks
that's why is a little bit complicated

Comment: Are the 'a','b' and 'c' elements the modules you talk about ?

Comment: Do you need a regular intersect? Or what is the question? You need to clarify.

Comment: @Jad: yes, those are the modules

Comment: @jishi: I dont know what is a regular intersect, but check my new update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running jquery have a look at $.when, otherwise there are libraries like promises.js (explination here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rbuckton/archive/2010/01/29/promises-and-futures-in-javascript.aspx). The idea is the promise fires the event when the dependacies are ready and resolved.

Comment: The idea here is to be fast and simple and low-level as is the core of a framework. I can't implement a event system because is not needed in this case. Hardcoded is a better choice in this case